# I rendered this simple file normally the other day (render time ~1min) but now it suddenly won't start the rendering at all?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I've been doing some Boxcutter exercises to learn hardsurface modeling and got this model to render the other day normally but it simply wont begin rendering now. I've checked my settings and it should be working. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Here's the file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DAVvHlvGH2nAqzGUU3bKKX02Yj68qDXa

Comment: Hello :). There are some heavy particle systems, that take a looong time to load when rendering. Perhaps trimming them down a bit could help.

Comment: Can't believe i forgot about that sub particle system, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.